# Have latex warn when I refer to an item that occurs later?

Tags: cross-referencing

I'm writing a long mathematics book. Sometimes after I move things around, an internal reference (`\ref{...}`) will refer to an item that occurs later in the text. For example, a proof may (unintentionally) require something proved later in the book. Is it possible to have LaTeX automatically warn of this?

Comment: Welcome! Later at all or on a later page or in a later section or...? A minimal example which can be compiled to reproduce the situation would improve your chances of being well understood and getting useful help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could load the [varioref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/varioref) package and use that package's `\vref` instruction instead of the more basic `\ref` command.

By default, `\vref` adds page-related information to cross-reference call-outs whenever they refer to items that occur on pages before *or* after the call-outs themselves. By adding the instructions

```
\renewcommand\reftextfacebefore{}
\renewcommand\reftextbefore{}
```

in the preamble, the output of `\vref` will differ from that of `\ref` only if the item being cross-referenced occurs *after* the call-out.

Strictly speaking, this method doesn't generate a *warning* if the call-out occurs before the item itself. However, in combination with a package such as `hyperref`, the extra information generated by `\vref` ("Theorem 5 on page 65") should create an easy-to-detect visual flag. Once you're satisfied that your document doesn't contain any undesired forward-pointing cross-references, you could change all `\vref` statements back to `\ref`.

A full MWE is given below. Observe that the `\vref` statements on the first page generate additional output relative to what `\ref` produces, whereas the `\vref` statement on the third page does not.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varioref}
\renewcommand\reftextfacebefore{}
\renewcommand\reftextbefore{}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} % cross-references marked in red

\begin{document}
A cross-reference to equation \vref{eq:pyth}.

A cross-reference to equation \vref{eq:euler}.
\clearpage
\begin{equation}\label{eq:pyth} a^2+b^2=c^2 \end{equation}
\clearpage
\begin{equation}\label{eq:euler} e^{i\pi}-1=0 \end{equation}
A cross-reference to equation \vref{eq:pyth}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I do not claim that doing this is wise....

## *Caveat emptor...*

---

You could use something like this:

```
\usepackage{expl3,etoolbox}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_zeno_refs_seq
\msg_new:nnn { zeno } { Patch Failure } { Could~not~patch~#1~\msg_line_context:! }
\msg_new:nnn { zeno } { Patch OK } { Successfully~patched~#1~\msg_line_context:. }
\msg_new:nnn { zeno } { Prior Ref } { Cross-reference~before~label:~#1~\msg_line_context:. }
\apptocmd{ \label }
{
  \seq_put_left:Nn \l_zeno_refs_seq { #1 }
}
{
  \msg_info:nnn { zeno } { Patch OK } { \label }
}
{
  \msg_error:nnn { zeno } { Patch Failure } { \label }
}
\apptocmd{ \ref }
{
  \seq_if_in:NnTF \l_zeno_refs_seq { #1 } {} { \msg_warning:nnn { zeno } { Prior Ref } { #1 } }
}
{
  \msg_info:nnn { zeno } { Patch OK } { \ref }
}
{
  \msg_error:nnn { zeno } { Patch Failure } { \ref }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Basically, this keeps track of labels and checks if the reference is referring to an already issued label or not. If not, it says something like this:

> ```
> *************************************************
> * zeno warning: "PriorRef"
> * 
> * Cross-reference before label: fifth on line 77.
> *************************************************
> ```

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,etoolbox}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_zeno_refs_seq
\msg_new:nnn { zeno } { Patch Failure } { Could~not~patch~#1~\msg_line_context:! }
\msg_new:nnn { zeno } { Patch OK } { Successfully~patched~#1~\msg_line_context:. }
\msg_new:nnn { zeno } { Prior Ref } { Cross-reference~before~label:~#1~\msg_line_context:. }
\apptocmd{ \label }
{
  \seq_put_left:Nn \l_zeno_refs_seq { #1 }
}
{
  \msg_info:nnn { zeno } { Patch OK } { \label }
}
{
  \msg_error:nnn { zeno } { Patch Failure } { \label }
}
\apptocmd{ \ref }
{
  \seq_if_in:NnTF \l_zeno_refs_seq { #1 } {} { \msg_warning:nnn { zeno } { Prior Ref } { #1 } }
}
{
  \msg_info:nnn { zeno } { Patch OK } { \ref }
}
{
  \msg_error:nnn { zeno } { Patch Failure } { \ref }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\ref{first}\ref{second}\ref{third}\ref{fourth}\ref{fifth}\newpage
\label{first}\ref{first}\ref{second}\ref{third}\ref{fourth}\ref{fifth}\newpage
\label{second}\ref{first}\ref{second}\ref{third}\ref{fourth}\ref{fifth}\newpage
\label{third}\ref{first}\ref{second}\ref{third}\ref{fourth}\ref{fifth}\newpage
\label{fourth}\ref{first}\ref{second}\ref{third}\ref{fourth}\ref{fifth}\newpage
\label{fifth}\ref{first}\ref{second}\ref{third}\ref{fourth}\ref{fifth}\newpage
\ref{first}\ref{second}\ref{third}\ref{fourth}\ref{fifth}\newpage
\end{document}
```